# why doesn't the java thread start?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-native-interface

```
package keylogger;

public class TestKeys {
private static int i = 0;
private native void setWinHook();
private native void unregisterWinHook();

public static void main(String args[]) {

    TestKeys o = new TestKeys();

    System.loadLibrary("MyHook"); // load the library that registers the hook

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("After the call to System.loadLibrary");
        }
    };
    new Thread(r,"new thread").start();  
  }
}
```

When i start the program,`dll` is loaded and does it's work. But the statement inside the `run method` of `new thread` doesn't get printed. Why is that ? *Why doesn't the java thread start ?* The dll code doesn't return immediately. Infact there is no way it can return.

And :

*Does a new thread start when the program encounters a statement `System.loadLibrary`* ?

Comment: reason for downvote please :-||

Comment: Maybe the JNI_OnLoad function of your "MyHook" library is preventing you from reaching the Thread.start line. Did you check that ?

Comment: @Jerome As per the answer by [aix](http://stackoverflow.com/users/367273/aix) thread should start.

Comment: "and does it's work". What is "its work"? Does that work include exiting the process?

Comment: @EJP The third statement of the same paragraph mentions this. _"Infact there is no way it can return"_ . The dll is assigned a job. Till now i don't make the dll end it's job. i.e it never returns/exits

Comment: @SuhailGupta I have no idea what third paragraph of what text you are referring to, but if the method never returns, the code following the call will never be executed.

Comment: @EJP But the code following, is on a new thread.

Comment: @SuhailGupta But the code following that creates the new thread is never executed.

Comment: @SuhailGupta Because the prior method never returns. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: @EJP I was misunderstanding something. Thank you.

Comment: @EJP If i start a new thread from C program will it run the code following `System.loadLibrary` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does a new thread start when the program encounters a statement System.loadLibrary ?

Not unless the library creates one in its initialization section.

P.S. Does the behaviour change if you [`join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) the thread?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: Initialized, yes.

Comment: and the `dll` will hold the main thread  till it finishes it's work ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: I think there's some fundamental misunderstanding about when loading a DLL means. It means that the library is mapped into the process's address space, and functions are resolved. The DLL can also do some initialization, but that usually involves a trivial amount of work.

Comment: ok. Till the `dll` creates it's own thread, _(java's)_ main thread won't be free. Is it true or not ?

Comment: and why does the new thread created in the java program doesn't print the statement ?